# Trouble understanding a Lemma in Pastur's Paper

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

I'm having trouble understand Eq 3.51 Lemma 3.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.06188.pdf

The basic premise is

$$\begin{align}
&\eta _{j}(t)=t^{1/2}\eta _{j}+(1-t)^{1/2}q_{n}^{1/2}\gamma _{j},
\;t \in [0,1], \notag
\\&\eta _{j} =n^{-1/2}\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}X_{j\alpha }x_{\alpha n}+b_{j},
\label{eetaj}
\end{align}$$
where $X$ is $n\times n$ matrix with iid standard gaussian entries, $b$ is $n\times1$ with iid N$(0,\sigma^2)$ entries and $\gamma$ is $n\times 1$ vector with iid N$(0,1)$ entries. Define
$$K_{jj}(t)=(\varphi ^{\prime}(\eta _{j}(t)))^{2} $$
so that $K$ is a diagonal matrix. Further define
$$F_{j}(z,t)=(XS\mathcal{G}(z,t)SX^{T}\dot{K}(t))_{jj}.$$
where $$\mathcal{G}(z,t)=(SX^TK(t)XS-z I)^{-1}$$
Now, the author says that using the formula $E[Z f(Z)] = E[f'(Z)]$ for std normal random variables, we get the following
$$\mathbf{E}\{F_{j}(z,t)(t^{-1/2}\eta _{j}-(1-t)^{-1/2}q_n^{1/2}\gamma
_{j})\}=(tn)^{-1/2}\sum_{\alpha =1}^{n}\mathbf{E}\left\{ \frac{\partial F_{j}%
}{\partial X_{j\alpha }}\right\} x_{\alpha n}$$
where the partial derivative denotes the "explicit" derivative
(not applicable to $X_{j\alpha }$ in the argument of $K$ and $\dot{K}$. I've verified the identity about std normal RVs but I couldn't prove this equality. One idea was to condition on $\eta_j(t)$, however, then the RVs inside the expectation won't be standard normal anymore. Any help is appreciated.